# After using the delete method, the post request gives a bad request even though theres no problem in the code?

Tags: rest, mern

I have entered all required feilds but still it gives a bad requuest

```
{
  "message": "Please input all feilds",
  "stack": "Error: Please input all feilds\n    at C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\backend\\Controllers\\taskController.js:15:15\n    at asyncUtilWrap (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express-async-handler\\index.js:3:20)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:144:13)\n    at Route.dispatch (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\route.js:114:3)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\layer.js:95:5)\n    at C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:284:15\n    at Function.process_params (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:346:12)\n    at next (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:280:10)\n    at Function.handle (C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Documents\\SLIIT\\Y2S2\\ITP\\Shehans work\\Shehans work\\GlanProject\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\router\\index.js:175:3)"
}
```

I am trying use the post method to submit form data.It was successful at the begining but once i used the delete method i could not post and submit form data again

```
const setTask = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => { 
    const T = ({taskID, outputItemName, outputItemQty} = req.body);

    if(!taskID || !outputItemName || !outputItemQty ){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Please input all feilds");
    }

    const task = await Task.create({
        taskID,
        outputItemName,
        outputItemQty        
    });

    if(task){
        res.status(201).json({
            taskID : task.taskID,
            outputItemName : task.outputItemName,
            outputItemQty : task.outputItemQty,
            
    }
    )}else{
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error("Invalid user data")
    }
})
```